# How to solve a linear equation with algebra.js?

Tags: javascript, html, math, algebra

I'm trying to solve/evaluate an equation using algebra.js by nicolewhite and can't seem to get it right.
Here's the code i'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <script src="//algebra.js.org/javascripts/algebra-0.2.6.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <script>
      var Fraction = algebra.Fraction;
      var Expression = algebra.Expression;
      var Equation = algebra.Equation;

      var x1 = algebra.parse("1/5 * x + 2/15");
      var x2 = algebra.parse("1/7 * x + 4");

      var eq = new Equation(x1, x2);
      console.log(eq.toString());

      var answer = eq.solveFor("x");

      console.log("x = " + answer.toString());

    </script>

  </body>
```

I'm not sure linking the source js works here but it just gives me a blank page anywhere i try that code. I have defined the three variables as stated by the algebra author so I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are correct, you were not retrieving the script. I just edited your snippet (please forgive me). Note that I removed the protocol (http) from the URL. That allows the same protocol of the page to be used to retrieve the script - and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a blank page because you are not setting the answer to any html element. Your code is sending the output to the `console` so you should be able to see it there.

Try this to show the result on your page.

```js
var Fraction = algebra.Fraction;
var Expression = algebra.Expression;
var Equation = algebra.Equation;

var x1 = algebra.parse("1/5 * x + 2/15");
var x2 = algebra.parse("1/7 * x + 4");

var eq = new Equation(x1, x2);
console.log(eq.toString());

var answer = eq.solveFor("x");

console.log("x = " + answer.toString());

const output = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(output);
output.textContent = "x = " + answer.toString();
```

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the question. The original script (prior to my edit) had a "not found" error because the JS file was not being loaded.